# How to determine 10 K resistor on the schematic?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I have problem determining my 10 K resistor. I need the calculation. Please help me.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: Your schematic resolution makes it unreadable. Also, it's not clear what you want us to calculate. You gave the resistance, so current? VOltage? Dissipated power?

Comment: If it's 10K, what is there to determine?

Comment: I have updated your circuit image. You might want to make your question little bit more clear.

Answer (score 4):

You have two 10k pull-up resistors in your circuit. Their value is a compromise between the current they draw when the mosfets are off, and the speed at which the mosfets turn on.

Judging from the anti-parallel diodes the mosfets are used to switch relays or solenoids (not for PWMing), for which 10k might be a good choice. But nothing wrong with 1k, and I would feel a bit unconfortable with 100k, but that is without any calculation.

Are you aware that you probably need resistors in the 2N2222 base wires?

In your place I would probably grab a dual mosfet driver chip (Motorola, Microchip).